# Using HTTP Interceptor within a package

Tags: angular

I am trying to make my Angular control package that uses HTTP calls to use the same HTTP interceptor that is specified in the main project. I am using a package that wraps my controls project into a package (npm pack). The issue I have is, in my main project I am using an HTTP Interceptor to handle tokens For OWIN. In my controls package, I also make HTTP calls using HTTPClient, but the interceptor is not used. My control package is using (HTTPClient injected in constructor) and http.get, and the main application also makes http calls the same exact way. The interceptor is provided in the app.module of the main application.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Main projects app.module providers:

```
providers: [
    {provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy},
    ApplicationConfigService,
    { provide: APP_INITIALIZER, useFactory: loadConfigService , deps: [ApplicationConfigService], multi: true },
    MessageService,
    AuthService,
    DataService,
    AuthGuard,
    {provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: TokenInterceptor, multi: true},
    {provide: UrlSerializer, useClass: LowerCaseUrlSerializer }
  ],
```

Comment: You might have to import the `HttpClientModule` in the `AppModule` only, and not the child module.

Comment: @Reactgular that worked, thanks! I thought that may have done it but didn't try it because I assumed it would have failed to build if it was missing that component.